# to compare values of jsp page with the database values null pointer exception

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets

i want to compare the strings that are taken from form with the values with the table values... but there is nullpointerexception
2)how do i get resultset to not access the last record of the table

```
        String occid = request.getParameter("occid");
        String date = request.getParameter("Date");
        String firstname = request.getParameter("FirstName");
        String lastname = request.getParameter("LastName");
        String village = request.getParameter("Village");
        String sonof = request.getParameter("Son");
        String district = request.getParameter("District");
        String weight = request.getParameter("Weight");
        String bags = request.getParameter("Bags");
        String rate = request.getParameter("Rate");
        String amount = request.getParameter("Amount");
        String advanceamt = request.getParameter("Advance");

        String sql = null;
        PreparedStatement prest = null;
        List<AcceptBean> list = new ArrayList<AcceptBean>();

        sql = "Select * from ColdStorage.OccupantMaster";
        prest = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = prest.executeQuery();
        String first = "";
        String last = "";
        String vill = "";
        String son = "";
        String dist = "";
        while (rs.next()) {
            AcceptBean bean = new AcceptBean();
            first = rs.getString("FirstName");
            bean.setFirstName(first);
            System.out.println("first = " + first);
            last = rs.getString("LastName");
            bean.setLastName(last);
            System.out.println("last = " + last);
            vill = rs.getString("Village");
            bean.setVillage(vill);
            System.out.println("vill = " + vill);
            son = rs.getString("Sonof");
            bean.setSonOf(son);
            System.out.println("son = " + son);
            dist = rs.getString("District");
            bean.setDistrict(dist);
            System.out.println("dist = " + dist);
            list.add(bean);
        }
        for (AcceptBean s : list) {
            if ((first.equals(firstname) || first.equals("null")) && (last.equals(lastname) || last.equals("null")) &&
                    (vill.equals(village) || vill.equals("null")) && (son.equals(sonof) || son.equals("null")) &&
                    (dist.equals(district) || dist.equals("null"))) 

            {
                System.out.println("do nothing");
                ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
                RequestDispatcher rd = sc.getRequestDispatcher("/Index.jsp");
                System.out.println("it exists in database");
                rd.forward(request, response);

            }
```

the database values are -

OccId
FirstName
LastName
Village
SonOf
District

31
Sourodeep
bag
bengal
aurobindo bad
bengal

32
ARVINDBHAI
PARMAR
SAJOD
PARAGBHAI
SAJOD

67
divyang
parmar
bharuch
Arvindbhai
bharuch

72
urvashi
parmar
mumbai
arvindbhai parmar
mumbai

90
divyang
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL

91
divyang
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL

Comment: You might want to share which line of code the NullPointerException indicates.

Comment: lee it is giving null pointer expception on this line                if ((first.equals(firstname) || first.equals("null")) && (last.equals(lastname) || last.equals("null")) &&

Comment: @LeeMeador can u help me in dis ..i edited this question

Comment: Easiest way to leave off the last row of the table is to start by leaving the code as you have it. Then process all the rows and finally remove the last row you added to the list, once all of the result set is handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to Check for null

   if(first!=null)

2.If it is a null stirng, then `null` not equals `NULL` because you have used equals , use equalsIgnoreCase Instead.

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [`ResultSet#getString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29) say:

> the column value; if the value is SQL NULL, the value returned is null

So `last` is `null` for those rows for example, not the `String` `"null"`. You are therefore calling `null.equals`.

Test for `== null`, not `equals("null")`:

```
        if( first == null || first.equals(firstname) &&
            last == null || last.equals(lastname) &&
            vill == null || vill.equals(village) &&
            son == null || son.equals(sonof) &&
            dist == null || dist.equals(district) )
```

Comment: @DivyangParmar Can you be more specific, just for a sanity check I ran my code with *every* variable set to `null` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

check your

if(first!=null)

then compare the values with other